# python: поиск частичного совпадение в списке и вывод следующего элемента

Tags: python-3.x

```
reader = {'sdfsd - sdfdsf', '43252345', 'ecrf - wexex', '34534535', '233253', 'wwdwed - wedd'}
ch_1 = 'sdfsd - fxcf'
for row in reader:
    if ch_1 in row:
        list_1 = (row[row.index(ch_1) + 2])
        print(list_1)
    else:

        if (ch_1.partition('-')[0] + "-") in row:
            print(row[row.index(ch_1.partition('-')[0] + "-") + 2])
```

что то мне подсказывает, что частичное совпадение в индексе списка не вызвать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понял что вы хотите получить, но примерно так:

```
# поменял вид скобок, с теми скобками это set и ничего вообще нельзя сделать, значения лежат вперемешку
reader = ['sdfsd - sdfdsf', '43252345', 'ecrf - wexex', '34534535', '233253', 'wwdwed - wedd'] 
ch_1 = 'sdfsd - fxcf'

n = 2 # какой элемент по счёту мы хотим получить после совпадения
for i in range(len(reader) - n):
    if reader[i].partition('-')[0] == ch_1.partition('-')[0]:
        print(reader[i + n])
```

Вывод:

```
ecrf - wexex
```

Comment: а как указать не следующий элемент - а тот что после следующего в вашем коде?

Comment: @AleksandrChirikov Вы дополните вопрос - что именно вы хотите получить? Возможно, под вашу задачу всё же надо перебирать именно индексы. Постановка не очень понятная.

Comment: Если просто для всех элементов надо сразу второй брать, то просто в zip надо другой срез второй брать: [2::2], но я не понимаю, что конкретно хотите вы

Comment: есть список - в нём очень много индексов - мне надо прогнать часть искомого индекса через весь список и вытащить при совпадении второй индекс после искомого!

Comment: программа должна выдать ecrf - wexex

Comment: @AleksandrChirikov Поменял ответ на более универсальный

Comment: Или вам надо получить следующий элемент где есть тире всё-таки?

Comment: спасибо)))) заработало!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: такой ещё вопрос! а можно найденное запихать в список?

Comment: @AleksandrChirikov Ну, делаете до цикла result = [] и внутри цикла вместо print(...) делаете result.append(...)

Comment: спасибо))))))))

Comment: ещё вопрос) как в списке заменить все элементы содержащие  R1 на 1

Comment: @AleksandrChirikov Не понял, приведите пример )

Comment: list = { 'R1', '23424', 'dgfwh', 'R1'} надо сделать list = { '1', '23424', 'dgfwh', '1'}

Comment: Ну вы хотя бы научитель список в правильных скобках описывать, что за безобразие ))  list = ['1' if x == 'R1' else x for x in list] Кстати, лучше не называть переменную list - это ключевое слово Python, потом сюрпризы будут

Comment: спасибо) это меня java мракобесит ))))